# Merging/unifying two counters

Tags: counters

I have two (completely seperate) theorem counters, but I want them to behave as they were the same counter (incrementing the one counter increments the other, same for resetting). The obvious workaround, changing one counter in `\newtheorem`, is not possible, as these commands are part of a `.sty` used for a lot of documents.

How does one unify/merge arbitrary counters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\let\c@zzz=\c@xxx
```

will make the counters `zzz` and `xxx` use the same internal register.

Comment: perfect, for future reference: you have to surround this statement with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`